# extracting tabular data from excel sheet using r

Tags: r

How to extract tabular data from a spreadsheet(which has junk data too) using R.
 [click to view the spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgtbC.png).

i can write this in r-

```
xcelfile<-read.xlsx("LT257-Refuel 3 March2017.xlsx",sheetIndex=1,startRow=9,colIndex=c(1,2,3)))
```

but want a more generalized way which will work for any such file without actually mentioning the starting row to read from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your screenshot, it looks like you don't have any data at the top of your file that's farther to the right than an actual data column. If that assumption is true, you can use the following code to dynamically set the value of `startRow`:

```
min(which(complete.cases(read_xlsx("LT257-Refuel3March2017.xlsx"))))
```

## Why it works

```
test <- read_xlsx("test.xlsx")
# See the bottom of this answer for the dput output from test

cc <- complete.cases(test)
# Create a vector showing where there's missing data

cc <- which(complete.cases(test))
# Get a vector showing where there are TRUE values

cc <- min(cc)
# Find the earliest row that has a value in each column
```

## Example data

```
structure(
  list(
    `No copyright 2017` = c(
      "Made by Andrew Breza",
      NA,
      NA,
      "a",
      "0.20163499083126724",
      "0.22825468034535024",
      "5.0982213542989485E-2",
      "0.10281072980496486",
      "0.64909268750884885",
      "0.70355689088752538",
      "0.86041365822441651",
      "0.17703894784688834",
      "0.17436477104724901",
      "7.8210087926938621E-2",
      "0.62840230879652859",
      "0.47390519345520465",
      "0.17709432355627197",
      "0.21680508964340539",
      "0.42013016672732617",
      "0.27558526667241368",
      "0.73421400056622432",
      "0.3008573777830944"
    ),
    X__1 = c(
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      "b",
      "0.10530273672328228",
      "0.57362069130780791",
      "8.6190788221684689E-2",
      "0.93970062859291503",
      "0.98313592372911485",
      "0.69934659461539217",
      "0.67775289068563083",
      "0.18487308246868062",
      "0.13727414072992095",
      "0.97886937472912772",
      "0.33494682878761595",
      "0.38691583143160924",
      "0.22538745867671395",
      "0.78993890542175837",
      "0.54424684747789254",
      "0.6211545954458173",
      "0.52315172220522255",
      "0.9249434890424244"
    ),
    X__2 = c(
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      "c",
      "1.798394389715019E-2",
      "0.48852685697950471",
      "0.511135945041712",
      "0.15620166014476378",
      "0.18400930969357332",
      "0.56153224896656539",
      "0.20932061985098849",
      "0.73934609434573473",
      "0.6563390016659193",
      "0.44542823830895195",
      "0.40431302050322948",
      "0.69817110559609552",
      "0.22619605667502185",
      "0.31567993543368122",
      "0.66165692952282684",
      "0.49190019375595861",
      "0.85287531618000434",
      "0.95659649277422809"
    ),
    X__3 = c(
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      "d",
      "0.52978180616887405",
      "0.26248657154304644",
      "0.92492633566696458",
      "0.28845813234934969",
      "0.45675400607977801",
      "9.6399518093580605E-2",
      "0.70848994854955472",
      "0.47467197462769017",
      "0.54266110899628384",
      "0.15242767673773072",
      "0.62962185530884729",
      "0.79948863441696005",
      "0.97921292674380367",
      "0.95155896584036115",
      "0.61046228678401782",
      "0.36630750428703296",
      "0.92034619245493643",
      "0.30251636944016935"
    ),
    X__4 = c(
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      "e",
      "0.44520622146439093",
      "0.25763202918954686",
      "0.57157196576664482",
      "0.13855752627816653",
      "0.36486076569906845",
      "0.59198411405761164",
      "0.11101644469753646",
      "0.44819906683171207",
      "0.84090939808845988",
      "0.35965505274703058",
      "0.84780342228842287",
      "0.16713792608147138",
      "7.9855497761844196E-2",
      "0.59425596116302071",
      "0.20810432506625398",
      "0.50403916185284026",
      "0.349651850034845",
      "0.67659808045569292"
    ),
    X__5 = c(
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      "f",
      "9.8930955361685835E-2",
      "0.96547240641836818",
      "0.46440533344650992",
      "0.74076741685833791",
      "0.30181122840373564",
      "0.56538643074614503",
      "0.56788732925203778",
      "0.56375788819366213",
      "0.43462600598328394",
      "0.14261157268114866",
      "0.62537286750674947",
      "0.7437112765392242",
      "0.71769176920920108",
      "0.55005462908684066",
      "0.80882942650644041",
      "0.87673165877980208",
      "0.25589697540607192",
      "7.8168903385850808E-2"
    ),
    X__6 = c(
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      "g",
      "0.26582177818716768",
      "0.38097648784489491",
      "0.68959666363898542",
      "0.3320245351431016",
      "0.88082273061309824",
      "0.16884962926524261",
      "0.69780989348413147",
      "0.10538108497255883",
      "0.201521157744733",
      "0.11884857868727472",
      "0.23764189907094002",
      "0.16247009289992365",
      "0.50209884800617577",
      "0.72617734144415036",
      "0.28696520971352502",
      "0.31238776292429182",
      "0.98877064276115301",
      "0.11280008220991433"
    ),
    X__7 = c(
      NA,
      "Yup here",
      NA,
      "h",
      "0.14841467723151391",
      "3.9819114921856968E-2",
      "0.56837064320267927",
      "0.85395489379904677",
      "0.69661506623045577",
      "0.98474764955059735",
      "2.5098690275612845E-2",
      "0.94616226982864171",
      "0.80519284764792409",
      "0.89294962679085987",
      "0.1608941340883776",
      "0.89888281402638381",
      "0.98458500475763688",
      "0.11892983339802443",
      "0.16990338725067256",
      "0.89301913292795732",
      "0.48977127816954613",
      "0.481585804429011"
    )
  ),
  .Names = c(
    "No copyright 2017",
    "X__1",
    "X__2",
    "X__3",
    "X__4",
    "X__5",
    "X__6",
    "X__7"
  ),
  class = c("tbl_df",
            "tbl", "data.frame"),
  row.names = c(NA,-22L)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
xcelfile<-read.delim("LT257-Refuel3March2017.xlsx")
```

and try to write the name of your .xlsx files without blank spaces between.